# GIMP Gradient Tool Issue

Tags: gimp

I can't use the gradient tool at all. I have a certain area selected, and try to use the shape gradient in that area, but I just can't! There's a circleslash on the icon. I tried every shape, selecting and deselecting, on every layer, and it just isn't working.

Comment: Hello Tikkit, welcome to GDSE, we're glad to have you! Could you maybe [edit] your question and include a screenshot of what you are seeing? This issue may be caused by a number of things, it might be easier to spot if we can see what you see. You can read the introduction in [help] on how to improve your question even further. Feel free to contribute to the site by asking more questions or answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

From your description you are trying to make a gradient on a color-indexed image (a GIF, possibly). The gradient tool cannot work on such images, you have to convert them to RGB (`Image>Mode>RGB`).

Note however that the gradient generates many colors. When exporting again in a  color-indexed format such as Gimp, all the colors in the image will be shoe-horned into the 256 colors of the color map. Many colors of your image will shift a bit, resulting in a grainy/pixellated look.

Answer (score 0):

*Why are you doing `Select`->`None`?*

**The way it works now:**

1. you select the area you want to fill with a gradient
2. set a start and end point
3. then you can dynamically move the points
4. When you have it how you like, then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

***Edit:***  I think you are doing `Select`->`None` before you hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to finalize your gradient. If you select none before you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then yes, I have the same issue you are experiencing.

**`This is a copied answer, but worked for me`**
Link to original https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gradient-fill-doesn-t-work-the-same-in-Gimp-2-10-2